# Determine if user runs TWRP or CWM recovery

Tags: android

I have created a small app that flashes multiple rom update files in one click.

This app only works with TWRP for now but I want to make it compatible with CWM aswel.

I need to from java determine what recovery system the user is running on their phone.

Is there some kind of property file on the file system which reveal that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved by reading file contents of `/sdcard/recovery.log` and searching for `TWRP`